# How to use tags with function constructors

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor, tags

For learning purposes, I am trying to copy an html page layout. with just javascript. For this I figured I would use function constructors for the html tags. Since they will repeat and all I need to change is the text in it. The page is divided by 3 div boxes in those I want to place it all. I can see them on console but it won't display in the browser.

I have tried swapping innerText out for createTextNode, but unsure what text node does in comparison to the other text methods. Also tried a few different ways of arranging it but i'm fairly new so it was just wrong.

```
//one of three container used for layout of elements.
let topContainer = document.createElement('div')

//Function constructor for the h1
let NameH1 = function (text) {
    this.text = text;
    var typeH = document.createElement('h1')
    typeH.innerText = `${this.text}`;
    }

//input for first headline
var firstText = new NameH1('Hello world!')

//adding text to container and then container to the page.
topContainer.appendChild(firstText)
document.body.appendChild(topContainer);
```

The chrome console shows nothing except the script tag on the body atm. Before it did show the div tags but nothing inside them. When logging NameH1 in chrome it does show the hello world text.

I want to re-use tags and display them in a proper format. There are different use cases for the text tag so I might be using the wrong one somewhere. My main goal is just to get a better grip on OOP

Comment: add `return typeH` to your function

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at the return earlier but it did not help I the setup at that time. Guess I got sloppy not troubleshooting it step by step. I thought the typeH maybe had nowhere it could be stored at first.

Comment: So from my understanding typeH is returned and added when I specify to append uniQ.

Comment: yes that's it..

Comment: That must have sounded silly. I thought maybe it was a case that I had the entire layout of adding tags wrong. So it would try to add hello world without the typeH changes. Thanks for helping a noobie with probably some basic stuff :)

Comment: It seems fairly pointless to use a constructor with new when you don't use any of a constructor's special features. You can build a much more generic HTML element builder if you pass the tag name and attributes you want set like `let h1 = makeElement('h1', {textContent: 'Hello world!'})`.

Comment: True I was making it with the hopes that later on I would be able to use some for of those, maybe closure. But at the moment it's just 3 divs with each some tekst and icons. So I imagine I would just make 3 h1 objects in the script like this. Was hoping that having a function for tags would reduce iteration and make it possible to group texts in one spot to adjust easily. thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @RobG It tried your suggestion of the HTML tag builder. When viewing it in chrome I can see the h1 (p in the example ) in the dom via the console. But there is no actual text connected to it. Tried some of the seperate methods of adding text too did not help. I must be totally overlooking something here.       let topContainer = DDcument.createElement('div');
let firstP = document.createElement('p',{textContent: 'some text'}); 
topContainer.classList.add('topcontainer');
document.body.classList.add('body');
topContainer.appendChild(firstP);
document.body.appendChild(topContainer);

Comment: If you have another question, ask it as a question, not a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor doesn't have a return statement, so by default it returns its *this* value, which is a new instance of itself. The element created by *createElement* is left behind for garbage collection.

Probably what you meant to do is something like:

```js
let topContainer = document.createElement('div')

// H1 constructor
function NameH1(text) {
  let typeH = document.createElement('h1');
  typeH.innerText = text;
  return typeH;
}

let firstText = new NameH1('Hello world!');
topContainer.appendChild(firstText);
document.body.appendChild(topContainer);
```

Using a constructor this way is somewhat gratuitous as it doesn't use any of the special properties of a constructor and just means more typing with *new*.

Consider instead a generic function that takes a tag and options to add as attributes, e.g.

```js
function genElement(tagName, options) {
  let props = ['textContent','innerHTML'];
  let el = document.createElement(tagName);

  Object.keys(options).forEach(key => {
    // Add properties
    if (props.includes(key)) {
      el[key] = options[key];
    // Add attributes
    } else {
      el.setAttribute(key, options[key]);
    }
  });
  return el;
}

let h1 = genElement('h1',{id: 'h0', textContent: 'Hello World!'});

console.log(h1.outerHTML);
document.getElementById('d0').appendChild(h1);
```

```html
<div id="d0"></div>
```

However, you may quickly end up with many *if..else* blocks with different logic for attributes, properties, data-* attributes, classes, boolean attributes, listeners and so on (e.g. as the very limited example above does with properties and attributes).

Building such a function is a useful learning experience to discover many of the quirks in HTML and the DOM, particularly in regard to attributes and properties. But I think eventually it becomes a compatibility and maintenance nightmare.